# How to render a piece of data stored in an external model without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am trying to display a User's name on top of a box where they enter their Employee # in a form, without having to refresh the page.

For example, they enter their # and then after they click/tab onto the next field, it renders their name on top, which comes from the database, so the user knows they've entered the correct info. This name is stored in a separate model, so I try to retrieve it using the "id/number".

I am not too familiar with AJAX but after reading a few similar questions it seems like an AJAX request would be the most appropriate way to achieve this. I tried to make a function **get_employee_name** that returns the name of the person based on the way I saw another ajax request worked, but I'm not sure how to implement this so it displays after the # is entered.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,  blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee_number
```

This is the model where the name is stored

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
```

I was reading I can add to the "attrs" in the widget an 'onchange' part, but I am not too familiar with how to approach this and tying it to the ajax request from forms and not the html.

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')
```

**views.py**

```
class EnterExitArea(CreateView):
    model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
    template_name = "operations/enter_exit_area.html"
    form_class = WarehouseForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do submission stuff..


def get_employee_name(request, id):
    employee = get_object_or_404(Salesman, id=id)
    return HttpResponse(employee.slsmn_name)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('get-employee-name/<int:id>/', views.get_employee_name, name='ajax_get_employee_name'),
]
```

The ajax request I tried to create is at the end of this html. I modified a similar request I found, but it does not actually display anything on the screen, not sure if I'm missing an area where the request is actually never being called, as I am not too familiar with how these types of requests work.

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <h1 id="url" get-employee-name-url="{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %}">{{ employee_name }}</h1>
            <div>
                {{ form.employee_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#id_employee_number").change(function () {
            var employee_number = $(this).val();
            var url = '/enter-exit-area/get-employee-name/' + employee_number;

            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:'GET',
            data: {
                'id': employee_number
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
                $('#employee_name')[0].innerHTML = employee_name;
            },
            error : function (data) {
                var error_message = data['error'];
                $('#employee_name')[0].innerHTML = error_message;
            }
            });
        });
    </script>

{% endblock main %}
```

What could be causing nothing to render on the page? I assume there needs to be a place where the onchange() goes, but I'm not sure where this would be in since the form fields are it's own thing, without tags.

Comment: First thing to check is whether you're getting an AJAX error.   There are a couple of ways to do that.  First, you could just look at the developer tools in the browser, and watch the Network.   It should show you the request going out, and the response.  It's most likely that you're getting a 500 response from the get-employee-name function.   You could also put an error handler in the ajax call, like ```error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("error: "+textStatus); }``` to see what's going on.

Comment: Are there any errors in console? Are you getting data in success response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're defining you endpoint in the urlpatterns[] as follows:

```
path('get-employee-name/<int:id>/', views.get_employee_name, name='employee_name'),
```

the associated view should expect **id** a second parameter following **request**; for example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def get_employee_name(request, id):
    employee = get_object_or_404(Salesman, id=id)
    return HttpResponse(employee.slsmn_name)
```

In the ajax call, I would rather use an absolute url:

```
var url = '/get-employee-name/' + employee_number;
```

(please note the leading backslash) otherwise, the visited url would be relative to the current page;
If the app's urlpatterns in included in the root one with a suffix, add it as required:

```
var url = '/the_app/get-employee-name/' + employee_number;
```

Also, you don't need 'data' in the ajax call parameters, since you're expecting the employee_number from the url.

Finally, I would add:

```
console.log('data: %o', data)
```

to the success callback to make sure you're receiving what you expect

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but nothing renders on the page still (and it seems that nothing gets called either according to the Network)

Comment: mhhh ... try calling "http://127.0.0.1:8000/the_app/get-employee-name/123/" from the browser (remove or replace "the_app" suffix as required, and use a valid record it). Does it work ?

Comment: grrr I realize now that the view is returning a string, while it should return an HttpResponse object instead (sorry, I'm just looking at the code here on SO and didn't run it). I'll correct my response in a minute. You're code is well done and it will surely work, dont' give up ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for dedicating the time! I have no clue how most of this works so it has just been tons of trial and error (and googling)

Comment: You're doing very well ! ... keep on trying

Comment: I added the changes you suggested and I'm not sure why I'm getting `Reverse for 'ajax_get_employee_name' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['operations/get\\-employee\\-name\\/(?P<id>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

Comment: That's due to the "{% url 'operations:ajax_get_employee_name' %}"  tag in the template; it complains because the value for the required "id" parameter is missing. Just remove this tag entirely, it's not needed